# Data structure to use for a basic file system

Tags: java, data-structures, hashtable, binary-tree

I am practicing a few interview questions and I found an interesting one which was to build a basic file system / terminal. Because this is an interview question, this file system is probably a basic one that involves adding files and directories, and adding files and directories within directories. Another feature would be to print out all the directories and files in a logical manner. This all has to be done without using the `Collections` library

I was curious to what data structures I would use to implement this file system? What I had in mind was either a `hashtable` or a `B tree`.

Hashtable would a really fast look up time. However it would use up a lot of memory. I was planning to use prime numbers as my bucket size.

B tree would be much more memory efficient. However look up times would be slower.

Or possibly both?

ex:

all files stored in `hashtable` node while directories are storied in a tree node that can branch out to other directory nodes or hashtable.

Another question I have is: which one would *seem* easier to code or implement the `print all` function?

Comment: A B-tree is closer to what is really used, NTFS uses that. Some hashing could perhaps be used to increase performance, especially with caching, although caching is normally a layer above the file system implemented in the OS.

Comment: This is more of an "algorithmic strategy" question than a specific programming question.  For a file system you need to understand what type of use you may want ... whether large numbers of files can be in each directory; how long the names can be; information about file size; handling of permissions ...

Comment: If the question is being asked as you're posing it, "Design a simple file system," then the expectation is probably for you to start asking intelligent questions so that you can actually design something that makes sense for the needed functions and performance.  Real file systems make all kinds of performance trades: speed, space overhead, ACID properties, journaling recovery and logging for forensics, etc. I'd be looking for questions showing you understand the problem space, not necessarily a canned answer on which data structure to choose.

Comment: A hash table would be a really bad idea. If somebody asked you to list all of the files in the `"foo\bar"` directory, you would have to search all of the keys. It would be an O(n) operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best datastructure for a file system is a Tree. If you think of it, it naturally models the hierarchy of a directory structure

```
dir1
  dir2
    dir2a
      file2b
  dir3
    dir3a
      file3b
      file3c
      dir4
        file4a
```